# Probability of one vaccinated mother having a baby that didn't catch the flu, and another unvaccinated mother having a baby that caught the flu?

Tags: probability

A regional health board keeps records of the numbers of babies who get the flu when they are under six months old. It also records whether the mother had a flu vaccination during the six months before the baby was born.

[image: probability table]

If from among the group recorded in the above table, two babies and their mothers are chosen at random, then what is the probability that one mother was vaccinated and had a baby that didn't catch the flu, and the other was unvaccinated and had a baby that caught the flu?

I tried to answer this question by adding 0.3511/0.3538 and 0.0863/0.6462, but could not get the correct answer of 0.0606. How do I solve this?

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to answer this without knowing what percentage of mothers have been vaccinated.  Have you left something out?  Also, please don't link graphics when you can easily type the information, as in this case.  Nobody wants to keep flipping back to a graphic in order to answer your question.

Comment: @saulspatz Just the probability table information alone is sufficient as I show in my answer.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  In particular, see the section on arrays to learn how to compose a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the first mother being the one who was vaccinated and had a baby that didn't catch the flu (with a probability of $0.3511$) and the other mother being unvaccinated and had a baby that caught the flu (with a probability of $0.0863$). As these $2$ mothers, and babies, were picked at random, you can assume they are independent events, so the probability of this situation is the product of the probabilities, i.e.,

$$P_1 = 0.3511 \times 0.0863 = 0.03029993 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

However, as it's just as likely the situation occurred in the opposite order, i.e., the first mother was unvaccinated & the second one was vaccinated, then the probability of this occurring is also $P_1$, so the total probability would be

$$P_T = 2 \times P_1 = 0.060599986 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Rounding $P_T$ to $4$ decimal places gives your stated correct answer of $0.0606$.

Comment: Thanks so much for answer. For this question, I drew up a probability tree, and I added 0.3511 and 0.0864 as they are on different branches. Why is this incorrect?

Comment: The probability tree diagram is for **one** object, e.g., a coin being tosses once or twice such as shown at [Probability tree diagrams](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-tree-diagrams.html). However, this is for $2$ separate mothers, each with a child, with each one's probability being independent of each other. For the first mother, there are $4$ possibilities, $p_1$ to $p_4$, as shown on your chart, with $p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 = 1$. For each possibility there are $4$ possibilities for the second mother. If you have $p_{ij}$ being $i$ occurring for the first mother, with ...

Comment: @ChrisUren (cont.) probability $p_i$, and $j$ occurring for the second mother, with probability $p_j$, you have $p_{ij}=p_i p_j$. If you add all of these, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^4 \sum_{i=j}^4 p_{ij}$, you'll see you get $1$, which is because it covers all possible situations. If you wish, you can consider the combination of these $2$ mothers as being the "entity" for the probability tree, with there being $4 \times 4 = 16$ possible branches, each with probability $p_{ij}$. Of these $16$, only the $2$ I mention in my answer fit what's being asked, with their sum being the $0.606$ probability.

Comment: @ChrisUren One more thing is that with the probability tree you drew initially, the sum of $0.3511$ and $0.0864$ would be the probability of one of the mothers, either the first or second, to have been vaccinated and had a baby that didn't catch the flu, *or* to have been unvaccinated and had a baby that caught the flu. Do you see why this is the case?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still having a bit of trouble visualizing the probability tree. In my book, they draw the first two branches as V and V' (vaccinated mother and unvaccinated), and the branches which go out from V are F and F', and the branches which go out from V' are F and F'. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @ChrisUren There are many possibilities for a probability tree (pun intended). What I outlined was for the entity/object being the combination of both mothers, and I was considering all possibilities at one level. Your comment is about just *one* mother, with the first level being her vaccination status, and the second being that of the baby (I assume this is the F and F' you mention). With the table, there's no real need for the probability tree you mention, with its main use being in cases where you have it but not a table, in which case you can create a table from its values.

Comment: @ChrisUren The comments are not a proper place to discuss probability trees in too much detail, so if you're still unsure about them, I suggest you ask another question, ensuring it's clear & you provide sufficient context (e.g., what you've tried, where the problem came from, etc.). With this question, I thought it had sufficient context, but some others did not so it was closed as you can see. I'd like to help you get it reopened. If you would at least edit your question to state where the problem comes from, I can then also help refine your question to hopefully make it acceptable here.